# How to find a character and replace the entire line in a text file

Tags: vb.net

How would I go into a text file find a certain character then replace the entire line that the character was on?

Here's an example of the text file:

```
    line1
    example line2
    others
    ......
    ....
    id: "RandomStr"
    more lines
    ...
```

I need to find the line with `"id"` and replace it.
The edited text file should be:

```
    line1
    example line2
    others
    ......
    ....
    "The correct line"
    more lines
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to read each line of the text file, like this:

```
For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("PathToYourTextFile.txt")

Next
```

Next, you need to search for the string you want to match; if found, then replace it with replacement value, like this:

```
Dim outputLines As New List(Of String)()
Dim stringToMatch As String = "ValueToMatch"
Dim replacementString As String = "ReplacementValue"

For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("PathToYourTextFile.txt")
    Dim matchFound As Boolean
    matchFound = line.Contains(stringToMatch)

    If matchFound Then
        ' Replace line with string
        outputLines.Add(replacementString)
    Else
        outputLines.Add(line)
    End If
Next
```

Finally, write data back to a file, like this:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("PathToYourOutputFile.txt", outputLines.ToArray(), Encoding.UTF8)
```

Comment: Everything worked fine except for the line outputLines.Add(Replace(line, replacementString)) so I replaced it with outputLines.Add(replacementString) and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @ThatGuyJay - ah yes, that was a typo, typing too fast. Thanks for catching that, updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

First match the line against a regular expression. Then, if the match succeeds, output the new line. I don't know VB.net, but the function in C# would be something like:

```
void replaceLines(string inputFilePath, string outputFilePath, string pattern, string replacement)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputFilePath))
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputFilePath))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (regex.IsMatch(line))
            {
                writer.Write(replacement);
            }
            else
            {
                writer.Write(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would call it like:

```
replaceLines(@"C:\temp\input.txt", @"c:\temp\output.txt", "id", "The correct line");
```

Hope this helps.